# async_work_group_copy on an array of structs of uint

Tags: c, arrays, struct, opencl

I want to able copy an array of structs from global to local memory.  The structs are of the following type:

```
typedef struct{
  uint boo;
  uint moo;
} boo_moo;
```

I have an array of these guys pointed to by a boo_moo* called B.  I want to be able to copy the contents of B in global memory to an equivalently large array called B_loc in local memory.

Unfortunately, my kernel's workgroup sizes do not map well to this operation, so I am trying to use async_work_group_copy.  The problem is that async_work_group_copy expects a gentype, which a boo_moo* is not.

Is there a way that I can cast B and B_loc to a gentype so that async_work_group_copy works without having to change my array's initial declaration or doing an extra copy in global memory?

Ideally, I'd still like to be able to reference B like so:

```
A[i] = B[i].moo;
```

I've seen there is something called as_type, but I haven't seen it used on arrays.  It would be awesome if I could tell async_work_group_copy to treat B and B_local as two uint2*.

```
async_work_group_copy((uint2*)B_loc, (uint2*) B, num_elements, 0);
```

However, when I do that in the kernel, AMD's OpenCL compiler complains:

```
invalid type conversion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing memory address space qualifiers. Here is the fixed code:

```
async_work_group_copy((__local uint2*)B_loc, (__global uint2*) B, num_elements, 0);
```